# My addClass() event handler is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table tr:odd".addClass("highlight");
    // .....
}
```

I have `HTML` for 4 table rows and a class in `CSS` that should change the odd rows color. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(".table tr:odd".addClass("highlight")`, forgot `)`

Comment: if you have applied class to that table as class="table" than only put ".table"

Comment: Please show an example of your HTML in future as well. We have to assume your `table` element has a class of `table` on it for this example to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo. Forgot bracket

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table tr:odd").addClass("highlight")

                     ^
                     |
```

I am of course assuming your example was truncated as you do not close the DOM ready handler.

A shorter version is:

```
$(function() {
    $(".table tr:odd").addClass("highlight")
});
```

Both these examples assume your HTML has a `table` *class* on the `table` *element*:

e.g.

```
<table class="table">
  <tr></tr>
  ...
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have html like this then,

```html
<table>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Try like this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table tr:odd").addClass("highlight");
});
```

Comment: For more information on jQuery selectors refer http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

@ Jeffrey Kola Abodunde 
The code sample you provided has a typo.

**jquery syntax sumamry**

jquery object  = $

element at which effects needs to be applied = $(".table tr:odd")

effect to be applied : addClass

Therefore your code becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table tr:odd").addClass("highlight")
});
```

you were missing closing bracket before addClass method.

Answer (score 0):

if u understand ur question correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table tr:odd").addClass("highlight")
}
```

Should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".table tr:odd").addClass("highlight");
});
```

but i think you want to refer to the element  
ur are now referring to the  table class, which maybe does not exist.

So it would become:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table tr:odd").addClass("highlight");
});
```

Though if u have more tables within your page, u will target all tables.
I would recommend provide a id for that specifc table, so u will only target that table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table#tableid tr:odd").addClass("highlight");
});
```

hopes this helps goodluck